# Creating a nested XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to create an nested XML file for my current application.

The inputs data for the XML are taken from the following form.Problem that i am facing is for the  block.

Inside this block i have to take data from datagridview and have to save the data to the XML:

```
Table Name  Field           FieldType
Table1           f1          Search
Table1           f2          Update
Table2           f1          Search
Table2           f2          Update
```

The XML structure is given here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<database>


-<databasedtls>

<databasename/>

<path/>

<port/>

<user/>

<password/>

</databasedtls>


-<tables>


-<table>

<tablename>TABLE1</tablename>


-<FIELDS>


-<Search>

<field/>

<field/>

</Search>


-<Update>

<field/>

<field/>

</Update>

</FIELDS>

</table>


-<table>

<tablename>TABLE2</tablename>


-<FIELDS>


-<Search>

<field/>

<field/>

</Search>


-<Update>

<field/>

<field/>

</Update>

</FIELDS>

</table>

</tables>

</database>
```

Please help me regarding this.....

Comment: You can use XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the .NET XMLSerializer.  It allows you to serialize objects to XML.  here are two good links

This gives good basic examples of how to use the XML Serializer
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This introduces XML Attributes, you can use these on your own classes to control what the output XML look like when you serialize a class instance
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This would require you to build a few classes, my recommendation based on your structure

Classes:

- database
- databasedtls
- table
- Field(abstract)
- SearchField(extends Field)
- UpdateField(extends Field)

these classes should have the appropriate properties based on the xml structure for example database should have a databasedtls property and a list of tables.

If the above is too complex, or is too much of a time investment, you could do string manipulation or modify a XMLDocument object directly, but i recommend against that if you can.

That sort of code can prove difficult to maintain, and is more prone to supporting bad OOP practices, but they are also options so you know.